# Reading a CSV file line by line and producing streams with some lines sent with a random delay

Tags: csv, random, apache-kafka, stream

I am reading concurrently 3 CSV file line by line and sending them to a message queue (Apache Kafka). The data rows are ordered by increasing timestamp values. I am simulating the streams by looking at the last timestamp and at the new timestamp and make a thread sleep for the difference of the two timestamps. I do this in order to simulate the production of the messages.

Now I want to have some of those messages delayed by a random amount of time and have prepared a function that put the thread to sleep for a random amount of time and chooses randomly when to perform this operation.

When I do that I put to sleep the entire reading of the CSV file by delaying all the subsequent messages that have to be produced.

Probably I am lacking experience in doing this stuff, but I don't know how to randomly put to sleep one of the messages that I am producing without delaying all the messages that have to come?

```
//Read the CSV file line by line, serialize into object and put to sleep fo
public void readLikesEventStreamCSV(
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader, StreamproducerApplication.StreamProducer producer) throws IOException {
    String last_timestamp = "";
    StreamWaitSimulation sleep = new StreamWaitSimulation();
    try {
        String line;
        line = bufferedReader.readLine(); //read the first line. we do nothing with it.
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            final String[] lineArray = pattern.split(line);

            LikesEventStream value = new LikesEventStream
                    .Builder()
                    .personId(Integer.parseInt(lineArray[0]))
                    .postId(Integer.parseInt(lineArray[1].equals("") ? "-1":lineArray[1] )) //TODO: handle this empty string problem in a cleaner way.
                    .creationDate(lineArray[2])
                    .build();
            //Here the code will wait before sending the LikesEventStream value created above
            sleep.wait(last_timestamp, lineArray[2]);
            last_timestamp = lineArray[2];

            //This sends the object to a topic in Kafka
            send(value, producer, likesTopicName);
        }

    } finally {
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

A message that is sent to a topic looks like:

```
{"personId":721,"postId":270250,"creationDate":"2012-02-02T01:09:00.000Z","sentAt":1328141340000}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've got so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could fork off a thread for each delayed message.  That lets your main processing continue while that one thread sleeps:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long timeToWait = 2000L;
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try { Thread.sleep(timeToWait); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                System.out.println("Writing delayed message here");
            }

        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runner);
        thread.start();

        System.out.println("Processing continues after forking off message delay");

    }

}
```